# What can I do about the compiler require a semicolon at the beginning of a line,

Tags: c, compiler-errors

When I try to compile this c code, the compiler says `error: expected ',' or ';' before 'extern'`. It is referring to the line `extern int keyStates;`, which appears to be correct. If I add a semicolon in front like it suggests, `;extern int keyStates;` It works. I am confused because this is inconsistent with other code that defines a variable, and because I have never had to begin a line with a semicolon. I have tried ending the previous line with a semicolon, but I still get this problem. Also, it wouldn't make sense to end any of the previous lines with a semicolon since they are all defines. I have also tried making the variable non-extern, but that still has the same error. Is there anything I can do to avoid using a semicolon at the beginning of a line?

Here is my code:

```
#define REG_KEY_INPUT (*((volatile u32 *)(MEM_IO + 0x0130)))
#define MEM_IO   0x04000000

//Key Definitions from Nokturn's key demo
#define KEY_A 1
#define KEY_B 2
#define KEY_SELECT 4
#define KEY_START 8
#define KEY_RIGHT 16
#define KEY_LEFT 32
#define KEY_UP 64
#define KEY_DOWN 128
#define KEY_R 256
#define KEY_L 512

#define KEY_ANY 1023

#define A_KEY (keyStates & KEY_A)
#define B_KEY (keyStates & KEY_B)
#define ST_KEY (keyStates & KEY_START)
#define SEL_KEY (keyStates & KEY_SELECT)
#define DPAD_RIGHT (keyStates & KEY_RIGHT)
#define DPAD_LEFT (keyStates & KEY_LEFT)
#define DPAD_UP (keyStates & KEY_UP)
#define DPAD_DOWN (keyStates & KEY_DOWN)
#define R_KEY (keyStates & KEY_R)
#define L_KEY (keyStates & KEY_L)

extern int keyStates;

inline void getKeys()
{
    keyStates = ~REG_KEY_INPUT & KEY_ANY;
}

int* KEYS = (int*)0x04000130;
```

Comment: _When I try to compile this c code, the compiler says error: expected ',' or ';' before 'extern'_ -> can not reproduce, it compiles well for me.

Comment: Is that a header that you include some C file? How do you compile?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in whatever code goes before your file. That code lacks a semicolon at the end. Note that the compiler suggests adding it right at the beginning of your file (ignoring all `#whatever` directives). This is equivalent (from the compiler's perspective) to the end of previous file, where that semicolon really should be.

For example:

```
struct My
{
    ...
} // semicolon missing here! error will be reported on next file though
```

If your file is a header-file (it certainly looks so), look for the `#include` directive which includes it. The line before that `#include` directive will show where the problem really is.

For example:

```
some_file.c

#include "file1.h" // look for problem in this file
#include "file2.h" // this is the file where the error appears

...
int main()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: _That code lacks a semicolon at the end_ ... Where?

Comment: Right at the end of file. There is no semicolon there, but should be. See first example.

Comment: At the end of the file there is `int* KEYS = (int*)0x04000130;`, am I missing something?

Comment: The error is in a different file, not in the file which OP posted. See second example.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had a list of include files in main.c. The file included before the one I posted was missing the semicolon at the end!

Comment: @anatolyg oh I see, you are guessing based on the error message, good catch!!!!